# PHP how long till you can do this action again

Tags: php, sql

**I have a vote system.**

After a person votes, he will not be able to vote for another 12 hours.

What I want to do is, a echo that will tell him when he will be able to vote again.

Example:

```
You will be able to vote in 11 hours, and 04 minutes
```

***What I've thought of:***

When user finishes action, I will send a query with all details, and then set column 'Next_vote' to:

```
CURDATE() + 12 HOURS
```

And then do next_vote minus date(), And then it will give me the amount of hours/minutes till I can vote again.

But the problem is, I am not to sure how would I do this, therefore I need some help.

Is this a good way & should work? How do I do it?

EDIT::

```
    public function getTimeLeft($ip)
    {
        $this->get = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(CURDATE(), 'nextVote')) FROM auths WHERE voter_ip = :ip");
        $this->get->execute(array(":ip" => $ip));
    }

    public final function setNextVote($ip)
    {
        $this->insert = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE auths SET nextVote = CURDATE() + 12 HOURS WHERE voter_ip = :ip");
        $this->insert->execute(array(":ip" => $ip));
    }

            $minutes = floor($vote->getTimeLeft($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) / 3600);
            $hours = floor( ($vote->getTimeLeft($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) / 60) % 60);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQLs [timediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

Something like:

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(CURDATE(), 'NameOfField'));`

Then use your favourite server side language to turn the number of seconds into something nicer.

e.g. in PHP:

```
$totalSeconds = /* get from query using PDO or mysqli */

$hours = floor($totalSeconds / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($totalSeconds / 60) % 60);

echo "You will be about to vote in $hours hours, and $minutes minutes.";
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\includes\class\Vote.class.php:174 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\includes\class\Vote.class.php(174): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\index.php(644): Vote->getTimeLeft('127.0.0.1') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\includes\class\Vote.class.php on line 174

Answer (score 0):

Make a table with a field name "NextTime" (or whatever) and put your

```
CURDATE() + 12 HOURS
```

in there ..

If any update happen before that time .. ignore it

Comment: Yes, but I want to echo exactly like this:

"You will be able to vote in 11 hours, and 04 minutes"

Comment: Use PHP diff() function between NOW time with "Nexttime" field value

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL to get the time diff between the 2 dates, something like this:

```
SELECT
    TIMEDIFF('2013-05-12 10:00:00','2013-03-11 11:23:00') as total_time,
    HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2013-05-12 10:00:00','2013-03-11 11:23:00')) as hour_dif,
    MINUTE(TIMEDIFF('2013-05-12 10:00:00','2013-03-11 11:23:00')) as minute_dif
```

Result will be like this

```
total_time: 22:37:00
hour_dif: 22
minute_dif: 37
```

You can replace the dates with the current date field example: TIMEDIFF(date1,date2)

Comment: If you don't already know, you can use the `code` button in the editor to indent your SQL, other code and output samples.

Comment: first post ever! sorry if it make your eyes bleed.

Comment: It's not that bad! Just use the `edit` link above to tweak it `:)`